# Failed to create a 'System.Char' from the text '#' in WP7.1

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm creating MaskedTextBox in WP7.1 In that i want to set the Prompt char as '#'.

For ex: **##-##-#### ##:##**.  While running this i got an error message as

**Failed to create a 'System.Char' from the text '#'**

Please anyone can help me....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, post more details regarding your exception.
Also, consider using standard PasswordBox with PasswordChar property:

```
<PasswordBox PasswordChar="#"/>
```

**UPDATE:**

Use this char converter on your PromptChar property:

```
    public class CharTypeConverter : TypeConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
        {
            if (sourceType == typeof(string))
                return true;
            return base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
        }

        public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType)
        {
            if (destinationType == typeof(string))
                return true;
            return base.CanConvertTo(context, destinationType);
        }

        public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
        {
            if (value == null)
                return '_';

            if (value is string)
            {
                string s = (string)value;
                if (s.Length == 0 || s.Length > 1)
                    return '_';
                return s[0];
            }

            return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
        }

        public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
        {
            if (value != null && !(value is char))
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid prompt character", "value");

            if (destinationType == typeof(string))
            {
                if (value == null)
                    return String.Empty;
                char promptChar = (char)value;
                return promptChar.ToString();
            }
            return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(CharTypeConverter))]
public char PromptChar
{
    get { ... }
    set { ... }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did not used PasswordBox. I'm creating the custom MaskTextBox with the baseclass of TextBox. I have one dependance property named **PromptChar** with the type char. If i give  <mycontrol:MaskTextBox Mask="00/00/0000" PromptChar="#"/>. Then getting the mentioned error while running,

Comment: Have you debugged - what kind of value is sent to dependency property? Please post also relevant implementation of your MaskedTextBox class.

Comment: Yes, getting the value as '#' only. having the property as follows. public char PromptChar
        {
            get { return (char)GetValue(PromptCharProperty); }
            set { SetValue(PromptCharProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for PromptChar.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty PromptCharProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("PromptChar", typeof(char), typeof(MaskEditTextBox), new PropertyMetadata('_',OnPromptCharChanged));

Comment: in OnPromptCharChanged event, i have replaced the default char('_') with this mentioned char and setting the value.

Comment: Is the value '#' sent to the SetValue(..) - char or string type ?

Comment: Try adding 

[TypeConverter(typeof(Char))]

to your PromptChar property.

Comment: I tried [TypeConverter(typeof(Char))] also.same error getting. I could not move to chat. showing message "not enough to chat"